# drupal issue with install profile and domain module?

Tags: domain-access, configuration, drush, subsites

I had generated the make file with the contrib module domain.
When we enable the domain module, we just want to append the following code to the settings.php file.

```
include_once DRUPAL_ROOT.'/profiles/my_profile/modules/contrib/domain/settings.inc';
```

When i try to install this profile, i get an error

> Fatal error: Undefined function domain_get_primary_table()

this happends because when we install a profile the settings.php file overwrites the include settings.inc. So when it try to install the domain module it gives the above error and stops installation.
Anyone gave idea that how can we install the profile along with the domain module without this issue.

Thanks,
A.John

Comment: Do you use [drupal_rewrite_settings](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!install.inc/function/drupal_rewrite_settings/7)? An example is [Collecting and writing configuration settings to setting.php from an install profile](https://www.previousnext.com.au/blog/collecting-and-writing-configuration-settings-settingphp-install-profile)

Comment: @ClemensTolboom - Thanks for the suggestion, Its not working.